# What is the difference in the scopes of a controller and a directive's controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

What is the difference in the scopes of a controller and a directive's controller? I'm having a hard time understanding the difference and whether I should create controllers in the DDO for my directives.

Below I have a controller defined as MainCtrl and a controller inside the child directive. When I log the $scope to the console, they seem the same? Are they in fact the same object?

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', [])

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.first = 'first test'
    console.log($scope)
  })
  .directive('child', function() {
    return {
      //scope: {},
      template: '<div>{{second}}</div>',
      controller: function($scope) {            
        $scope.second = 'second test'
        console.log($scope)
      }
    }
  })
```

And HTML

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <child></child>
  </body>
```

Comment: short answer is yes they are the same when not using isolated scope in directive

Comment: ok, so if isolate scope is used then the directive's controller becomes totally separated from the rest of the controllers?

Comment: I would highly recommend to read up on [this article](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)

Comment: yes....sort of...the directive controller scope is a new scope not inherited when it is isolated

Comment: so when creating directives, is it better to create them with their own controller, or use a parent controller?

Answer (score 0):

Read this artical. It will be very helpful to you.

http://www.angularjshub.com/examples/customdirectives/scope/